# Using "send" to tcp socket/Windows/c

Tags: sockets, tcp

For c `send` function(blocking way) it's specified what function returns with size of sent bytes when it's received on destinations. I'm not sure that I understand all nuances, also after writing "demo" app with `WSAIoctl` and `WSARecv` on server side.

1. When send returns with less bytes number than asked in buffer-length parameter?
2. What is considered as "received on destinations"? My first guess it's when it sit on server's OS buffer and server application is notified. My second one it's when server application `recv` call have read it fully?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are using a (somewhat exotic) library, a `send` on a socket will return the number of bytes **passed to the TCP buffer** successfully, not the number of bytes received by the peer (see [Microsoft´s docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-send) for example).

When you are streaming data via a socket, you need to check the bytes effectively accepted into the TCP send buffer. That´s why usually a send command is inside a loop that will issue several `send`s if needed.

Errors in `send` are **local**: for example if the socket is closed by the peer during a sending operation (making your socket invalid) or if the operation times out (TCP buffer not emptying, i. e. peer not receiving data fast enough or some other trouble).

After all `send` is completed you have no easy way of knowing if the peer received all the bytes you sent. You´ll usually just issue `closesocket` and make sure that your socket has a proper [linger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/ns-winsock-linger) option set (i. e. only close after timeout or sucessfully finishing the send). Alternatively you wait for a confirmation by the peer (for example via a `recv` that returns zero bytes, indicating that the connection was gracefully closed).

Edit: typo

Comment: I believe that in most cases it's not necessary to use `linger`, the `close` call already waits for the data to be completely sent to the peer; also, AFAIK if the linger timeout occurs, a RESET is sent to the peer, which generally is not good